# How to remove Digits and whitespaces from a Stream?

Tags: java, arrays, filter, java-stream

I tried to convert args into stream. And then the stream has to be made uppercase, digits and whitespaces removed from the strings (not the whole string). 
creating stream and uppercase worked successfully and now I am stuck with the filter method and I dont get why my code is not working, already have done a little research as well.

```java
package A_11;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class A_11_g {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(args);
        stream.map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).filter(s -> Character.isDigit(s)).filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
                .forEach(name -> System.out.print(name + " "));
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say filter, do you mean you want to remove digits and whitespace from the String supplied or you want to remove the any String which contains digits/whitespace?

Comment: I want to remove digits and whitespaces from the stream and I thought filter would be right method for this purpose

Comment: What you have is a `Stream<String>` do you want to remove strings altogether with the criteria or characters within them? Though you may possibly be looking for `stream.map(String::toUpperCase)
                .filter(s -> !StringUtils.isNumeric(s) || !s.isEmpty())
                .forEach(name -> System.out.print(name + " "));`, with `StringUtils` from apache commons.

Comment: Yes but remove Strings containing Digits/Whitespace from the Stream, or remove Digits/Whitespace from the Strings of the Stream? Filter does the first, only accepting each element in to the filtered Stream if it satisfies the supplied Predicate.

Comment: oh ok now I understand I just want to remove every Digits/whitespace within the string of the stream not the string alltogether

Comment: @FrancisDrake then you need to `map` the uppercase string to the string formed as a result of operations like removing digit and whitespaces. something like `.map(s -> removeDigitAndWhiteSpaces(s))`

Comment: @FrancisDrake You should probably [edit] your question to make the requirements clear (in other words, incorporate the comment reply into the question itself).

Comment: @JiriTousek good point

Comment: @Holger It´s just what the task wants. I didn´t know how to directly put args into stream so I did it this way.

Comment: @Holger yes I tried severaly approaches and everyone failed, so I chose to it this way...

Comment: @Holger you are right now its working! :o have been using the wrong method before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter() produces a new stream containing elements of the original that satisfy a Predicate (the conditional you supplied). 
What you want is the map() function, which produces a new stream after applying a given function to each element of the original stream.

The below should do the trick, with some assertions at the bottom you can optionally use to verify in a unit test.

```
Stream<String> stringStream = Stream.of("unfiltered", "withDigit123", " white space ");

List<String> filtered = stringStream.map(s -> s.toUpperCase())//Can be replaced with .map(String::toUpperCase) if you want, but did it this way to make it easier to understand for someone new to all this.
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[0-9]", ""))//Removes all digits
        .map(s -> s.replace(" ", ""))//Removes all whitespace
        .collect(Collectors.toList());//Returns the stream as a list you can use later, technically not what you asked for so you can change or remove this depending on what you want the output to be returned as.

//Assertions, optional.
assertTrue(filtered.contains("UNFILTERED"));
assertTrue(filtered.contains("WITHDIGIT"));
assertTrue(filtered.contains("WHITESPACE"));
```

Comment: When you understand what `replaceAll("[0-9]", "")` does, you should easily recognize that it needs only a slight change, i.e. `replaceAll("[0-9 ]", "")`, to make it removing space characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really really* want to do it using streams, you need to apply the filtering logic on a lower level - not on stream of strings, by on the stream of characters within a single string:

```
System.out.println(
    "abcd 123 efgh".chars()
        .map(Character::toUpperCase)
        .filter(c -> !Character.isDigit(c))
        .filter(c -> !Character.isSpaceChar(c))
        .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining())
);
```

> ABCDEFGH

(The `mapToObj` part is there to avoid having to deal with custom collector that would be otherwise needed because the stream is an `IntStream` and not a regular Object stream.)

If needed, you could then wrap this into a stream that processes multiple strings - this above logic would then be inside a `map` operation on that stream.